# Install Tomcat and JDK via jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I have some idea to install the Tomcat & JDK via jenkins pipeline script. Using SSH agent i can able to connect my host machine. after the login i have to install tomcat then JDK.

```
node {
  def remote = [:]
  remote.name = 'my-machine'
  remote.host = 'my-machine-poc.com'
  remote.user = '*****
  remote.password = '******'
  remote.allowAnyHosts = true
  stage('Remote SSH') {
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done"
  }
}
```

Can you please some one help me if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using debian maybe: sudo apt get-install tomcat